# Is there a way to run the discord SDK code for C# in python?

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, discord

Im trying to use the discord SDK on my python app and the only non-unity and non-unreal way to do this is with C#

I have absolutely no idea how to code in C# but Discord says all i need is one line of code

I have tried converting my app to C# but some of the libraries on python isnt supported on C#

I also cant find any python wrappers for discord so i need a way to run the code from python

EDIT:

I have deciced to take the time to learn C# instead of looking for a quick patch like i usually do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, trying to use one language's SDK from another usually isn't trivial.  Your best bet to use it directly from Python is probably [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/), which allows you to call .NET APIs from Python.

If you're willing to use an unofficial API wrapper (I'm not sure if there's something special about the C# SDK), [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) exists as a solution.  That would hopefully avoid the need to use the C# SDK specifically.  Docs for that are [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: i have used discord.py for making discord bots how hard could it be